# UITableViewCell not being colored properly

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with 2 `header` sections (one for `Moderators` and one for `Members`).

It's a chat app, so after I get the members of a chat from the database and their corresponding status (ie member or moderator), I store them in an array and populate my cell based on that data.

The problem comes when I want to update the `contentView.backgroundColor` of the cell when the current logged in user matches the `user.id` that's being passsed to the cell.

I know for a fact that the members (all of them) are just 3, but when I print the `userId` and the `currentUserId`from the cell, I see it's called 4 times, which is odd.

```
  class ChatMembers: UIViewController { 
     var chatMembers = [
                    [UserModel](),
                    [UserModel]()
                  ]
     var participantsStatus = [String:String]()
     var chatId = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       observeMemberStatus()
    }

func observeMemberStatus() {
    if chatId != "" {
        Api.Message.observeChatRoomMemberStatus(forChatId: chatId, completion: { memberAndStatus in
            self.participantsStatus = memberAndStatus

            for member in memberAndStatus {
                if member.value == "moderator" {
                    Api.Users.observeUsersShort(withId: member.key, completion: { user in
                        self.chatMembers[0].append(user)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    Api.Users.observeUsersShort(withId: member.key, completion: { user in
                        self.chatMembers[1].append(user)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatParticipantSettingsTVC") as! ChatParticipantSettingsTVC
    let user = chatMembers[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.user = user
    cell.delegateChatParticipantsProtocol = self
    return cell
}
```

And the cell itself:

```
 var user: UserModel? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    guard let currentUserId = Api.Users.CURRENT_USER?.uid else { return }
    guard let userId = user?.id else { return }

      print("userId: ", userId)
      print("currentUserId: ", currentUserId)
      // 
    if userId == currentUserId {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("F0F4F6")
    }
}
```

The 2 print statements above print the following:

> userId:  ZgoQHyzAoPOS3amv
>   currentUserId:  T3kOyOWvl6aZhDY
>   userId: FtvyJ7FshZQuGpLR08
>   currentUserId:  T3kOyOWvl6aZhDY
>   userId: ZgoQHyzAoPOS3amv
>   currentUserId:  T3kOyOWvl6aZhDY
>   userId: T3kOyOWvl6aZhDY
>   currentUserId:  T3kOyOWvl6aZhDY

It basically prints out a user for a second time and I don't know why. (random user, sometimes it's the current user, which effects how the cell is being colored, and sometimes its a different user since the array is not being sorted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add else condition for :

```
if userId == currentUserId {
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("F0F4F6")
}
```

Because once the backgroundColor is changed how it will get reverted.

Add else condition :

```
if userId == currentUserId {
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("F0F4F6")
}
else {
    contentView.backgroundColor = "Default color"
}
```

or you can add in `cellForRowAt` :

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = "Default color"
```